# Checking for a cookie on every page - Efficient?

Tags: session, cookies

Is it poor design to check for a cookie on every page?

I want to know the users country which I will put in a cookie, but then my current design model checks the cookie on every page in order to show them the currency in the right format for their country.

Is this the best route, or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You could use url parts for that, but I actually consider using cookies a superior method.

Comment: Usually stuff like that can be placed in the session stored on the server and only one cookie is set to associate the session to the browser.

Comment: So each time a session ends, one needs to set up their country again? )

Comment: Consider http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is a session more superior to a cookie? If someone comes to the site, geoip their location and store in a session then I dont need cookies at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't. If there is a cookie set, the browser will send it anyways in the browser header and will be accessible via a variable.
It already will take up space in memory, checking if it's there only adds a very small bit of overhead.

If you have a site that has millions of visitors a day/hour it's worth looking into splitting microseconds.. but otherwise, just let it be.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should just do what you need but not more (as doing anything that is irrelevant to your further actions is pointless). But most likely you do not own site with massive traffic so you can simply do your check all the time even if you do not need to check result after all and you won't notice that (usually it happens that each page include some code that all pages share, and this code may do some checks etc even not all pages that include it needs that. I'd say that it is good you bother, but it is fine to leave as is (unless these checks take noticeable time - checking cookies is not one of them).